# Good PHP & MySQL Rating And Voting Script Tutorials?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any good rating and voting script tutorials that use PHP and MySQL? If so can someone point them to me so I can check them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [that one](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/PHP/Polls-and-Voting/1)? Also if you need some PHP basic knowledge you should take a look at this [tutorial](http://tut.php-quake.net/).

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

[This one](http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/rating_script.htm) looks pretty good too. Short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Up or Down Thumb Voting System - Saves user ratings in a text file by default but is also set up for MySql database.

http://templatz.co/rating-voting-scripts.php